# .html() of query not preserving the new line feed

Tags: jquery

I am appending data to jQuery Accordion like this

```
$('<div>').append($('<p>').attr('style', 'font-size:10px').html(strData));
```

where my strData is a line coming from database. This string has line breaks,
but once it get appended, it loses all its line break and show in one line.
For the same data when in alert it, it shows as I want.
How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In HTML, linebreaks are represented by `<br>` tags, not by CRLF characters.

You need to either replace CRLF characters by `<br>` tags, **or** to apply CSS `white-space:pre` on the containing HTML element and use `text()` instead of `html()`.

Replacing CRLF by `<br>` can be done at various ways. In the server side before returning the `strData` to JavaScript. For example, when you're using Java:

```
strData = strData.replace("\\n", "<br />");
```

Or in the client side using JavaScript itself:

```
strData = strData.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: Hey Balus, Thanks for answerring so quikc,i tried using the white-space:pre as well as white-space:per-line

Comment: For `white-space:pre`, use `text()` instead of `html()`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hey Balus,Thanks, really appreciate your help here  i was trying to do the same thing, but i guess was missing something, that worked for me

Comment: Man u are a Life saver !!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the string breaks with `<br>`:

```
strData.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br>")
```

This regexp should take into account OS-dependent difference in line-end symbols. Win - \r\n, Unix - \n, Mac - \r

Answer (score 1):

BalusC is correct.  If you cannot format the data in the database you could do this as well:

```
strData = strData.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "<br/>");
$('<div>').append($('<p>').attr('style', 'font-size:10px').html(strData));
```

Which will replace all linebreaks in your string with a "br" tag